# getting variables from txt file

Tags: c, file, variables, output

I have little code problem..Someone have any idea what could be wrong?

my code:

```
FILE *tiedosto;
char tiedostonimi[] = "input.txt";
tiedosto = fopen (tiedostonimi, "r");
char luokka, kaupunki[4];
int kuutio, vuosi, kuukausi, paiva;

fscanf(tiedosto, "%i&energialuokka=%c&kaupunki=%s&Vuosi=%i&Kuukausi=%i&pva=%i", &kuutio, &luokka, &kaupunki, &vuosi, &kuukausi, &paiva);
printf("%d %c %s %d %d %d , kuutio, luokka, kaupunki, vuosi, kuukausi, paiva);
```

line inside txt file:

```
22&energialuokka=A&kaupunki=ei&Vuosi=2010&Kuukausi=02&pva=22
```

("22" "A" "ei" "2010" "02" "22" are not permanent values.. given via website form and saved into text file)

Current

OUTPUT IS:

```
22 u ei&Vuosi=2010&Kuukausi=02&pva=22 831192666 0 -163754450
```

Comment: And what is the *expected* output? What is the output you want?

Comment: I wanna it print only those values given via form.. with what I mean

22 A ei 2010 02 22 in this case

Comment: Love to read it, love to listen to it, altough I do not understand a word ... :-)

Comment: try `fscanf(tiedosto, "%i&energialuokka=%c&kaupunki=%3[^&]&Vuosi=%i&Kuukausi=%i&pva=%i", &kuutio, &luokka, kaupunki, &vuosi, &kuukausi, &paiva);
`

Comment: Ah thanks.. I already fixed it with strtok but this one seem to work too :) <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when scanning for a string, the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of function will scan until a whitespace (or end of file, whichever happens first). You can't really use pattern-matching when scanning for a string. You can verify this quite simply by checking the return value of `fscanf`, in your case it should be `3` (since it scans the integer, a character and then the rest as a single string).

Incidentally this will of course lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you overwrite the array allocated for the string by quite a margin, as well as you printing the values of uninitialized local variables.

Instead it might be better to tokenize the input (hint: see the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function), to first split it on the ampersand `'&'`, and except the first value then split the other on the equality character `'='`. Then check each "key" to know what value to set.

Answer (score 2):

When scanning in a C-"string" do not use the address-of operator (`&`).

So this line:

```
fscanf(tiedosto, "%i&energialuokka=%c&kaupunki=%s&Vuosi=%i&Kuukausi=%i&pva=%i", &kuutio, &luokka, &kaupunki, &vuosi, &kuukausi, &paiva);
```

should be like this:

```
fscanf(tiedosto, "%i&energialuokka=%c&kaupunki=%s&Vuosi=%i&Kuukausi=%i&pva=%i", &kuutio, &luokka, kaupunki, &vuosi, &kuukausi, &paiva);
```

The background to this is, that if using the array variable without index operator it (already) decays to the pointer to (the address of) its first element.

Comment: Not that it really matters in this case, as `kaupunki` is an array. But good advice nevertheless.

Comment: Huuh .. dxxn you're right! Men simply is not build to percept more then one level indirection at once ... @JoachimPileborg